# How Can Fix This Error With C++Builder(Tokyo)...E2285 Could not find a match for 'sort<_RanIt,_Pr>

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, c++builder, builder

How Can Fix This Error With C++Builder(Tokyo)...E2285 Could not find a match for 'sort<_RanIt,_Pr>

**Source:**

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <deque>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

    // ----------------
    struct sfile {
        // ----------------
        u32 id;

        // ----------------

        // ----------------
        u32 daddr;
        u16 dport;
        u32 saddr;
        u16 sport;
        u16 pid;
        u8 mac[6];
        // ----------------
        u64 size;
        u64 nsize_left;
        string tag;
        string name;
        int color;
        int h;
        int seg_changed;
        u32 t;
        u32 timeout;
        // ----------------
        string data;
        u32 speed_temp;
        u32 speed;
        // ----------------
        bool keep;
        bool deleteed;
        bool tmp;
        int fx;
        // ----------------
    };

    // ----------------
               typedef set<sfile>file_set;
    file_set fs;
               typedef vector< const sfile*>SortedFsList;
    SortedFsList sfl;
              char FsSortMode=1;
    // ----------------

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
bool  FsSorter(const sfile *a, const sfile *b) {
            // --------------
            int r = 1; //FsSorting(a, b);
            // --------------
            if (r > 0) {
                return 1;
            }
            // --------------
            if (r < 0) {
                return 0;
            }
            // --------------
            if (FsSortMode > 0) {
                // --------------
                if (a->id < b->id) {
                    return 1;
                }
                // --------------
                if (a->id > b->id) {
                    return 0;
                }
                // --------------
            }
            // --------------
            if (FsSortMode < 0) {
                // --------------
                if (a->id > b->id) {
                    return 1;
                }
                // --------------
                if (a->id < b->id) {
                    return 0;
                }
                // --------------
            }
            // --------------
            return 0;
            // --------------
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void  FsSort() {
            // --------------
            sfl.clear();
            // --------------
            file_set::iterator i;
                // --------------
                sfl.push_back(&*i);
            // --------------
            sort(sfl.begin(), sfl.end(), FsSorter);
            // --------------
}
```

**OutPut: Error**

> // ---------------- ERROR [bcc32 Error] ClFile.cpp(557): E2285 Could
>   not find a match for 'sort<_RanIt,_Pr>(_Vector_iterator
>
> > ,_Vector_iterator >,void)'   Full parser context
> >         ClFile.cpp(533): parsing: void _fastcall CLSFILE::FsSort()

**Error Line:**

> sort(sfl.begin(), sfl.end(), FsSorter);

**Please give your ideas**

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: How much of the code you show is is really needed? Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us. And please copy-paste the full and complete error output (including any possible informational notes) and format it as code.

Comment: The error is a few lines up, where the code has one `if ... {` commented out but the `}` is still active. That puts the `sort` outside the function.

Comment: Free MS marketing: If you use VS2017 you don't even have to compile for the IDE to show the mismatch.

Comment: U8 is unsigned char

Comment: U16 is unsigned short

Comment: U32 is unsigned long

Comment: U64 is unsigned __int64

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this source is ok

thanks

```
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <deque>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#define COMPARE(a, b) if(a < b) return true; if(a > b) return false;

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
struct sfile {
    // ----------------
    int id;

    // ----------------
    bool operator < (const sfile& c) const {
        COMPARE(id, c.id);
        return false;
    }

};

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
typedef set<sfile>file_set;
file_set fs;
typedef vector< const sfile*>SortedFsList;
SortedFsList sfl;

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
bool FsSorter(const sfile *a, const sfile *b) {
    // --------------
    if (a->id < b->id)
        return 1;
    if (a->id > b->id)
        return -1;
    // --------------
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void FsSort() {
    // --------------
    sfl.clear();
    // --------------
    file_set::iterator i;
    // --------------
    for (i = fs.begin(); i != fs.end(); ++i) {
        // --------------
        sfl.push_back(&*i);
        // --------------
    }
    // --------------
    sort(sfl.begin(), sfl.end(), FsSorter);
    // --------------
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner) : TForm(Owner) {
    FsSort();
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What did you change? Why did that fix your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Before line

```
sort(sfl.begin(), sfl.end(), FsSorter);
```

there is unnecesary closing bracket. (sort is outside function body)

Comment: Post edit.  typedef unsigned char u8;
typedef unsigned short u16;
typedef unsigned long u32;
typedef unsigned __int64 u64;